# Update post on save

Tags: save-post

I am trying to work out how to change details of a post after its status has changed.

I would like to change the title of the post by appending the post id number to it. Here is the code that I'm working with now, but it doesn't change the post's title:

```
function update_post_info( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

// Stop anything from happening if revision
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) return;

//get post type
   $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

// If this isn't a custom post, don't update it.
// if ( "cbre_access_form" != $post_type ) return;

     //run codes based on post status
      $post_status = get_post_status();
      if ( $post_status != 'draft' ) 
      {
         if ( isset( $_POST['post_title'] ) ) {
           //stuck on this part not changing post title
           $ppt = 'test title - '.$post_id;
           update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_title', $ppt );
         }
      }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_info', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post's title (`post_title`) is not saved in meta data; it's a field within the post table.

Here's an updated version of your original code.

- [Infinite loop is
  prevented](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)
  by removing and then readding the `wpse246957_update_post_info`
  callback.
- Post title is successfully saved with the suffix `- $post_id` [A
  check is in place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018803/3059883) to
  prevent the suffix from being re-added if it has already been added.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse246957_update_post_info', 10, 3 );
function wpse246957_update_post_info( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // Stop anything from happening if revision
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'wpse246957_update_post_info' );

    // get post type
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );

    // If this isn't a custom post, don't update it.
    // if ( "cbre_access_form" != $post_type ) return;

    // run codes based on post status
    $post_status = get_post_status();
    if ( $post_status != 'draft' )  {
        if ( isset( $_POST['post_title'] ) ) {

            $suffix = ' - ' . $post_id;
            if ( ! preg_match( '/' . preg_quote( $suffix, '/' ) . '$/', $_POST['post_title'] ) ) {
                wp_update_post( [
                        "ID"         => $post_id,
                        "post_title" => $_POST['post_title'] . $suffix,
                ] );            
            }
        }
    }

    // re-hook this function
    add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse246957_update_post_info', 10, 3 );
}
```

Personally, I'd probably append the suffix before outputting the title in your template file or wherever you are outputting the title because there could be some edge case with the approach above when it comes to re-saving the post title.

Comment: I am getting the following : 
Missing argument 2 for wpse246957_update_post_info(), 
Missing argument 3 for wpse246957_update_post_info()
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
But after going to the posts it has added the number.

Comment: Woops! I fixed the re-hooking of `wpse246957_update_post_info` so that the priority and parameter numbers are specified. That should clear up the warning.

Comment: Thanks that works! only issue I found is it stops my custom title changing unless post is saved twice as I am using acf and picking two fields to save as the title in the first instance.

Comment: Happy to help, Sam! I'm not familiar with using ACF, but I *really* do suggest appending the ` - $post_id` suffix during output to avoid these kinds of edge cases. One route you could take would be to use the [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter. You could add conditionals in the filter so that you're only affecting the desired posts. Alternatively, you could just concatenate the suffix directly in the template file.

Comment: I just noticed it has the same numbers as the acf plugin updater add_filter('acf/update_value', 'jb_update_postdata', 10, 3); Can I amend one to trigger after the other?

Comment: You could try changing the priority of `wpse246957_update_post_info` so that it fires later (so use 99 instead of 10, for example). Make sure to update the priority in each `add_action` call above. I still think [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter is the better all around approach here though! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48914/discussion-between-sam-miller-and-dave-romsey).

Comment: Great code, thanks. Clever to unhook and re-hook.

Answer (score 0):

`post_title` saved in the `posts` the table as `post_title` not in the post_meta; Also you have to remove the `save_post` hook and then add because `wp_update_post` results in save_post being fired and it will create the [infinite loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post#Caution_-_Infinite_loop).

```
function update_post_info( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

// Stop anything from happening if revision
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) return;

//get post type
   $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

// If this isn't a custom post, don't update it.
// if ( "cbre_access_form" != $post_type ) return;

     //run codes based on post status
      $post_status = $post->post_status;
      if ( $post_status != 'draft' ) 
      {
     if ( isset( $_POST['post_title'] ) ) {
       $my_post = array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,
        'post_title'   => $_POST['post_title'].' - '.$post_id,
       );
        if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

            // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
            remove_action('save_post', 'update_post_info');

            // update the post, which calls save_post again
            wp_update_post( $my_post );

            // re-hook this function
            add_action('save_post', 'update_post_info');
        }
       }
      }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_info', 10, 3 );
```